# WPF DataTrigger stops applying IsExpanded to Expander if user manually expands

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger, expander

I want an expander to expand if a flag in the VM is set.  I also want the user to be able to override this and expand/collapse at will.  The following code doesn't work, the timer kicks in and the expander expands and collapses repeatedly - then If you click the expander manually it swiches too - but the trigger fails to expand or collapse the expander.  Its of course as if the manually keyed value is set and is taking priority over the Trigger Setter.

```
<Expander Header="Test" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <Expander.Style >
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
       <Setter Property="IsExpanded"  Value="True"></Setter>
       <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding DataContext.AmSet,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"></Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </Expander.Style>

  <Expander.Content>
            <Border Background="AliceBlue" Width="50" Height="50"></Border>
  </Expander.Content>
```

The VM has a dummy timer that just switches the flag to trigger the update as below

```
public class vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public vm()
    {
        t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
        t.Start();
    }
    bool _AmSet = false;
    public bool AmSet
    {
        get { return _AmSet; }
        set
        {
            _AmSet = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("");
        }
    }
    void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        AmSet = !AmSet;
    }
    System.Timers.Timer t;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to do this with a DataTrigger? It could be achieved easily with a two-way binding.

`<Expander Header="Test" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsExpanded="{Binding AmSet, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Comment: I had simplified the code, AmSet in my real code is in fact an enum - I wanted to use differing enum values to control when the expander opened and closed automatically. I wanted this to be in XAML and off the view model. Its arguable whether a Boolean in the VM encapsulating the same functionality and bound to IsExpanded is the right place for the logic and it what you suggest works fine and is probably what I'll do BUT I'd still like to know why the trigger stops working ?